# Can a tensor name belong to different name scopes in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like tensors and variables in Tensorflow to belong to different name scopes, so that I can build different training operations by selecting different subsets of variables.

For example this code does not seem to work:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
    with tf.variable_scope("bar"):
        v=tf.get_variable("v",[1])
        print(v.name)
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='foo'))
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='bar'))
```

Because as output I get:

> ```
> foo/bar/v:0
> < tf.Variable 'foo/bar/v:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref >
> []
> ```

and instead I would like tensorflow to recognize the variable declared as belonging at the same time to the two different namescopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name scopes in TensorFlow are hierarchical, so your `bar` scope is actually `foo/bar` and you should query it as such:

```
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='foo'))
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='foo/bar'))
```

Prints:

> ```
> [<tf.Variable 'foo/bar/v:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>]
> [<tf.Variable 'foo/bar/v:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>]
> ```